# Confidence Interval for Regression with Input-dependant Variance

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, experiment-design, mse

I am currently building an optimal designed Experiment. 
The design will have 20 runs, which will be replicated 10 times, so the total number of runs will be 200.

In order to compute the confidence interval I use the well-known formula:

$$
\hat{y}(x_0) = t_{\alpha /2, df(error)}+\sqrt{MSE\cdot x_0^{(m)}(X'X)^{-1}x_0^{(m)}}
$$

This gives me an confidence interval for the whole design space.

What bothers me, is that the Variance (=MSE) is independant of $ x_0 $, it is just a **mean** squared error. In reality, my measuring device is more or less precise, depending on the measured point.

Through my replicated runs, I am able to calculate a Variance $ \sigma^2  $ for each measured point (=pure error), and thus would be able to use this information in order to compute the MSPE for each point. The same way, I am able to calculate the model error (=LoF) in each measured point. This way I could obtain $ MSE=MSPE+MSLF$ in every point, and thus have an Input dependant variance. The values of the MSE between the points could be interpolated.

**To recap:**
can I use a MSE which is not constant over the whole design space, but takes different values in every measured point, in order to compute the confidence interval which takes into account the non-uniform variance in the design space?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: After a bit of Research, I found that in order to do a Regression, one has to assume that there is Homoscedasticity, i.e. that the variance is constant in the design space. Would that mean, that in this case (inout dependant variance), a Regression is not the right tool?

Comment: I think that if there is Input dependant variance, one has to use a weighted Regression.